# How do I use firebase token in mysql?

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am coding an app on ios and Android. In this app, entity will be able to create account and from this account, create events. Users will receive notification when an event is created in terms of his favorite entity.

I managed to send a notification with firebase (for android at the moment) from php with the token taken in log in android studio.

So, is it the good way to store each token in mysql database where I could select the favorite of each token and send the notification from php when the event is created ?

Do I have to use firebase database ? If yes, what I have to do in firebase ? How does firebase database run ? I don't find explicit tuto about it...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Firebase Topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). You only need to worry about subscribe and unsubscribe user. And when you are sending the message out, you only need to specify the topic, instead of array of tokens.

Comment: In this case, I have to associate a topic name to each entity and use it when the user add a favorite. When I make the notification in php, I use the topic name in curl and firebase do the job. Is it OK ? Can I see in firebase all the topic created ?

Comment: You can see them in 'Cloud Messaging' > 'Compose notification' > Topic dropdown. I havent found any api that lists them. You need to keep track yourself (it's still much easier than keeping track of tokens IMO).